# Get Default Payment Source (default card) for Stripe Customer?

Tags: stripe-payments

I created a POC with a customer/credit card in Stripe and I logged into my dashboard within Stripe and was able to see this customer has a default source (the test credit card I added) associated correctly. It shows this card is the default source.

When I run this .Net code:

```
 var customerService = new CustomerService();
 var stripeCustomer = await customerService.GetAsync(customerId);
```

To get that customer, it returns everything correctly except his source. All of the fields I had hoped I can find it from are empty! I want to know his default payment source so I can show it on the front end with a little icon to indicate it's default.

DefaultSource, DefaultSourceId, and Sources properties are all blank/null.

Is there a way to have Stripe return it, or do I need to do something else? I tried the 'expand' property for the GetAsync method but that threw an error saying the above properties are not expandable (i.e. I can't ask Stripe to expand/return Source).

Any ideas what I can do?

FYI I also tried this:

```
  var paymentMethodService = new PaymentMethodService();
  var cards = await paymentMethodService.ListAsync(new PaymentMethodListOptions  {   Customer = customerId, Type = "card"});
```

and there doesn't seem to be a property anywhere that says the card is default (although it does correctly return all cards). I believe Stripe documentation states the Customer is the holder of the default source, not the card object. What gives?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using Payment Methods, since your payment method list call has the results you expect, which means the customer likely doesn't have any `sources`. You can try that again with the properly pluralized `expand[]=sources` if you do know your Customer has Sources attached.

For Payment Methods, there is no general default for the Customer. For one-time Payment Intents, you must always specify the `payment_method` from among those attached to the Customer for [future payments](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse#web-create-payment-intent-off-session).

For paying invoices (related to recurring subscriptions, eg), you can set the [`invoice_settings.default_payment_method` for Customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/update#update_customer-invoice_settings-default_payment_method). This only applies to invoices.

Comment: Thanks - but the thing is, when I log into Stripe I see the default source for this customer.

Comment: I used the Stripe CLI to add a new subscription - this has scripts which generated the customer, a credit card, etc. . When I log into Stripe I see it all there, and it has a default source. However trying to interact with this in .net is yielding no sources. Is this why? And what is the difference between a payment method and a payment source lol